# How to get the content of the lists in NetSuite (ItemList, expensesList, etc) in NetSuite

Tags: php, web-services, netsuite, php-toolkit

I'm trying to get related lists and expenses of a vendorBill record (or any record really). When I do a basic transaction search, these two show up as NULL in the searchResponse, even though the record in question has one of each.

Do these not show up in the search result? If not, how do I get them. I'm using netsuite's php-toolkit.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging around, I've finally solved this. By default when you do a search, it's only going to return body fields. You need to set this to false:

```
$service = new NetSuiteService();
$service->setSearchPreferences(false, 1000, true);
```